# How to draw a circular circuit using circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

[image]

How can I draw a circuit like this in circuitickz?

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed. Please show your attempt and people will suggest modifications to realize this figure.

Comment: I am new in this field so didn't know how I should approach.

Comment: You got an answer below, but as an example: you could have drawn the straight parts with circuitikz (very easy), and then posted this to ask how to add rounded wires to it (harder to do).

Comment: Thanks for making me understand.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this can get you started:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.2]
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[R=$r$, *-*] (1.8,0) node[anchor=north] {$a$}
    (0,0) to[R=$r$] (0,2)
    (0,0) to[R=$r$] (-2,0)
    (0,0) to[R=$r$] (0,-2);
    \draw (0,0) circle (2);
    \path (45:2) node[circ] {} node[anchor=south west] {$b$} {};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

You can just draw arbitrary paths with the regular `\tikz` commands, such as the circle. To place contact nodes, you can use a `\path` and place a `\node` with option `circ` on it (or just use `\node[circ] (45:2) {};`).

[image]